# JSF dynamic resource path

Tags: jsf, resources

How can I use the resource variable to create a dynamic path?

```
<ui:repeat value="#{backgroundImageBean.images}" var="image"> 
      <p:graphicImage value="#{resource['/path/#{image}']}" 
       style="width: 100%; height: 100%" /> 
</ui:repeat>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `name` attribute instead of `value` attribute. The `value` attribute takes an URL while the `name` attribute takes the sole resource name already. It's then under the covers resolved the same way as `#{resource[name]}`.

```
<p:graphicImage name="path/#{image}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be solved in one of the two ways:

1. Embed the `'/path/'` part into your model so that `#{image}` would return the full path to the resource;
2. Create an alias for the to-be-generated image path using `<ui:param>` and use it when accessing the resource:

   ```
   <ui:repeat value="#{backgroundImageBean.images}" var="image">
       <ui:param name="path" value="/path/#{image}" />
       <p:graphicImage value="#{resource[path]}" /> 
   </ui:repeat>
   ```

If you're insisting on doing the logic without using a parameter and your environment supports EL 2.2+ then you can use [`String#concat()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29) in your resource expression:

```
#{resource['/path/'.concat(not empty image ? image : '')}'
```